# Oracle 12: Join on comma-separated list?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a view called 'companies' which I cannot modify:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------+--------+------------------------+
| company_id | company_name       | ceo    | cfo    | legal_contacts         |
+------------+--------------------+--------+--------+------------------------+
| 1          | johnson and son    | pid111 | pid333 | pid444, pid567, pid999 |
| 2          | Pepperville apples | pid777 |        | pid345                 |
| 3          | Cats LTD           | pid123 | pid321 |                        |
+------------+--------------------+--------+--------+------------------------+
```

and also a view called 'contacts':

```
+-----------+-------+----------------------+
| person_id | name  | email                |
+-----------+-------+----------------------+
| pid111    | john  | john@gmail.com       |
| pid333    | steve | funkylover@mail.com  |
| pid444    | mary  | mar123@ymail.com     |
| pid999    | joe   | joe.bloggs@gmail.com |
| pid777    | louis |                      |
| pid345    | carol | carol@carolssite.com |
| pid321    | ellen | ellen.deg@gmail.com  |
+-----------+-------+----------------------+
```

And the end goal is for me to write a query which cross-references the person ids and shows emails and company like:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| company | ceo            | legal_contacts                          |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 1       | john@gmail.com | mary123@ymail.com, joe.bloggs@gmail.com |
| 2       |                | carol@carossite.com                     |
| 3       |                |                                         |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way for me to join or process this comma separated list of identifiers in a query without writing a function or process?

You can assume 'legal contacts' will have at most 25 identifiers, always in the same format, always separated by a comma

Comment: It is very bad db design to store values as csv. Normalize your tables

Comment: "I have a view called 'companies' which I cannot modify"...

Comment: I really think you should look at the ddl of the view, `companies`.  Is the source of `legal_contacts` a csv column?  If that is not the case, I would **strongly** recommend looking at its foreign keys associated with `contacts` and the `company` table (there must be) and re-think the sources of this requirement.

Comment: @PatrickBacon Yep it's a CSV at source, unfortunately. It's not stored anywhere in the database in a normalized format, and I cannot modify the table or the view. The real tables/ views are actually much more complicated than my simplified example in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split the list of `companies.legal_contacts` using regular expression, then join the result set with contacts to get the email addresses (join twice to get `ceo` mail too) and then re-concatenate the emails using `listagg` function:

```
SELECT co.company_id, p1.email, LISTAGG(p2.email, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p2.email)
  FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT company_id, ceo, REGEXP_SUBSTR(legal_contacts, '[^, ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS single_contact   
          FROM COMPANIES
       CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(legal_contacts, '[^, ]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL) co
  LEFT JOIN CONTACTS p1 ON co.ceo = p1.person_id
  LEFT JOIN CONTACTS p2 ON co.single_contact = p2.person_id
 GROUP BY co.company_id, p1.email;
```

if the `companies.legal_contacts` can contain many values, the use of regular expression changes a bit for performance reasons and you must use a MULTISET.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! by copying your example, I was able to get my real issue solved as well. I'm not familiar with this 'LEVEL' construct you're using (and honestly just blindly copied you to make my real solution work. 
If I wanted to read more about it, what should I google?

Comment: `LEVEL` is a pseudocolumn you can use to relate more records to each other. Search for "Hierarchical Queries" (`CONNECT BY` is the key word). In this particular case the hierarchical query is used to split a string, but the most common use is to get data in a tree-structure with parent and child nodes.

Comment: [`level`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm) is a pseudocolumn available in `connect by` queries, that indicates the level in a hierarchy. If you use `connect by` just for its ability to generate rows, as is the case here, `level` (or `rownum` for that matter) becomes an ascending sequence representing the current iteration.

Answer (score 2):

This is an awful data format, but you seem to know that.  Here is one method:

```
select c.company, c.ceo,
       listagg(co.email, ', ') within group (order by co.person_id) as emails
from companies c join
     contacts co
     on ', ' || legal_contacts || ', ' like '%, ' || co.person_id || ',%'
group by c.company, c.ceo ;
```

Comment: This is the "quick and dirty" solution which works quite well if the query is ad-hoc. You can't forget the words at the beginning of the list (`OR like co.person_id|| ',%'`), at the end of the list (`OR like '%, '|| co.person_id`) and as single value in the list (`OR = co.person_id`). I would also use `LEFT JOIN` to avoid deleting companies without legal contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a function which helps you to normalize the data (pehpaps create your own view)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SplitString(LIST IN VARCHAR2, Separator IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE IS
    OutTable VARCHAR_TABLE_TYPE;    
BEGIN    
    SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, LEVEL)) 
    BULK COLLECT INTO OutTable
    FROM dual                           
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LIST, '[^'||Separator||']+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
    RETURN OutTable;    
END SplitString;
```

Then the query would be this:

```
WITH com AS 
    (SELECT company_id, company_name, ceo, cfo, 
        imp_util.SplitString(legal_contacts, ', ') AS legal_contacts
    FROM companies)
SELECT company_id, ceo.email AS ceo, 
    LISTAGG(legal.email, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY legal.person_id) AS emails
FROM com
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts legal ON legal.person_id MEMBER OF legal_contacts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts ceo ON ceo.person_id = ceo
GROUP BY company_id, ceo.email;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SQL> WITH companies (company_id, ceo, legal_contacts)
  2       AS (SELECT 1, 'pid111', 'pid444, pid567, pid999' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION
  4           SELECT 2, 'pid777', 'pid345' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION
  6           SELECT 3, 'pid123', NULL FROM DUAL),
  7       contacts (person_id, email)
  8       AS (SELECT 'pid111', 'john@gmail.com' FROM DUAL
  9           UNION
 10           SELECT 'pid333', 'funkylover@mail.com' FROM DUAL
 11           UNION
 12           SELECT 'pid444', 'mar123@ymail.com' FROM DUAL
 13           UNION
 14           SELECT 'pid999', 'joe.bloggs@gmail.com' FROM DUAL
 15           UNION
 16           SELECT 'pid777', NULL FROM DUAL
 17           UNION
 18           SELECT 'pid345', 'carol@carolssite.com' FROM DUAL
 19           UNION
 20           SELECT 'pid321', 'ellen.deg@gmail.com' FROM DUAL),
 21       sco
 22       AS (SELECT company_id,
 23                  ceo,
 24                  REGEXP_SUBSTR (REPLACE (legal_contacts, ' ', ''),
 25                                 '[^,]+',
 26                                 1,
 27                                 x.COLUMN_VALUE)
 28                     person_id
 29             FROM companies,
 30                  TABLE (
 31                     CAST (
 32                        MULTISET (
 33                               SELECT LEVEL
 34                                 FROM DUAL
 35                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 36                                         REGEXP_COUNT (legal_contacts, ',') + 1) AS SYS.odcivarchar2list)) x)
 37    SELECT s.company_id,
 38           c1.email ceo,
 39           LISTAGG (c2.email, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c2.email)
 40              legal_contacts
 41      FROM sco s
 42           LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts c1 ON c1.person_id = s.ceo
 43           LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts c2 ON c2.person_id = s.person_id
 44  GROUP BY s.company_id, c1.email;

COMPANY_ID CEO                  LEGAL_CONTACTS
---------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------
         1 john@gmail.com       joe.bloggs@gmail.com, mar123@ymail.com
         2                      carol@carolssite.com
         3

SQL>
```